# Is there anyway to link a jvector map to a search result?

Tags: javascript, jvectormap

So my requirement is that when user click on a specific country on a continent map(http://jvectormap.com/maps/world/south-america/), it needs to be redirect to a search result page with the items in related country. Can anyone help me to write the JS code?(Note: Im writting this custom JS for a shopify web)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the event listener `onRegionClick`

```
onRegionClick: function (event, code) {
    window.location.href = "yourpage?regionCode=" + code
}
```

Replace with the page you use to search results by region code.